# How do you add an attribute and node value when creating xml in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm using to groovy to create a dynamic XML document where each node can contain a value, attributes, or both.

For example

```
<root>
  <a id="123"> someValue </a>
<root>
```

I can't seem to find an example of where a node is created with both a value and a set of attributes.

Here's the line of code that creates a node (inside other code that creates the XML document and root element)

```
// node is a map, as is node.attributes
"${node.node_name}"(node.attributes.each { k, v -> "${k}:${v}"})
```

creates the following:

```
<a id=123 />
```

whereas:

```
"${node.node_name}""${node.value}"
```

creates:

```
<a>someValue <a>
```

What code would create a node with both the attribute and value set, looking like this:

```
<a id=123> someValue </a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code you're looking for:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer) 

xml.root() {
    a(id: 123, 'someValue')
}
println writer.toString()
```

Comment: Or indeed; `a('someValue', id: 123)`